# What does dollar symbol mean in windows batch file language?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I got the following file to setup environment for Tomcat:

```
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%/jre${jdk.windows.version}/win" (
    if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
        set JAVA_HOME=
    )

    set "JRE_HOME=%CATALINA_HOME%/jre${jdk.windows.version}/win"
)

set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xms1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

what does dollar sign and EL-like variables mean here?

**UPDATE 1**

This code is located in `setenv.bat` file, and it is called in `catalina.bat` normally

```
rem Get standard environment variables
if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat" goto checkSetenvHome
call "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat"
goto setenvDone
:checkSetenvHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat" call "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat"
:setenvDone
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `jre${jdk.windows.version}` is being replaced with the install directory name - but that specific part is not using Windows batch commands.  Perhaps it is in Tomcat's install routine.